# simplification of squared expression

Tags: exponentiation

I haven't done a math class in a while and I'm stumped on what seems to be a simple question.

How does

$$ ( [(k + 1)^2]/4 ) (k + 2)^2$$

simplify to 
$$  [ (k + 1)(k + 2)/2 ]^2     $$

What rule of simplifying exponents applies to this?

Comment: non what so ever (okay except that $ 4 = 2^2 $ just completely write it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step:

$$\frac{(k+1)^2}{4} \cdot (k+2)^2 = \frac{(k+1)^2}{2^2} \cdot (k+2)^2 = \left( \frac{k+1}{2} \right)^2 \cdot (k+2)^2 = \left( \frac{k+1}{2} \cdot (k+2) \right)^2 = \left( \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2} \right)^2$$

Do you understand what happens in each step?